# Count widgets of a certain type

Tags: customization, widgets, php, sidebar

How can I get the number (count) of, let's say, text widgets from a sidebar?

for eg. if I drop 4 text widgets in the sidebar, I want to get this number somehow from another widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call wp_get_sidebars_widgets(), and loop through each sidebar. Off the top of my head, text widgets have an ID like widget_text-$i.

Comment: All widgets have a numeric value on the end don't they, to indicate what instance of the widget it is(assuming a given widget supports multiple instances). Looks like the sidebar array stores widget names minus the `widget_` prefix though, so text widgets have a name like `text-1`, `text-2` and so on..